# Get limits of values from inequalites

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

[image]

My code above as below;

```
Assuming[{u >= 0, v >= 0, Element[{u, v}, Reals]}, 
   Solve[{0 <= u*v <= 1, 1 <= u/v <= 1}, u]]
Assuming[{u >= 0, v >= 0, Element[{u, v}, Reals]}, 
   Solve[{0 <= u*v <= 1, 1 <= u/v <= 1}, v]]
```

Comment: Condition ` 1 <= u/v <= 1` should be  `0 <= u/v <= 1` I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Reduce` gives additional infomation

```
Reduce[{0 <= u*v <= 1 && 0 <= u/v <= 1}, v] 
(*(u == -1 && v == -1) || (-1 < u < 0 && 1/u <= v <= u) || (u == 0 && (v < 0 || v > 0)) || (0 < u < 1 &&u <= v <= 1/u) || (u == 1 && v == 1)*)
```

The limits are  `-1/u<v<u &&-1<u<0`  and `u <v<1/u &&0<u<1`

```
Show[{RegionPlot[{0 <= u*v <= 1 && 0 <= u/v <= 1}, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -5,5}, PlotPoints -> 100], 
Plot[{u, 1/u}, {u, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Red}}]},PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! As you pointed out, there was a typing mistake in my question. I edited your answer slightly to get the expected result. Thank you again.Reduce[{0 <= u*v <= 1 && 0 <= v/u <= 1}, u]
Reduce[{0 <= u*v <= 1 && 0 <= v/u <= 1}, v]
Show[{RegionPlot[{0 <= u*v <= 1 && 0 <= v/u <= 1}, {u, 0, 5}, {v, 0, 
    1}, PlotPoints -> 100, GridLines -> {{0, 1}, Range[0, 6, 1]}], 
  Plot[{u, 1/u}, {u, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Red}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 150]

Comment: @Soon You're welcome!